# Testing a Firewall against outgoing UDP ports

Tags: networking, firewall, port, udp

I'm trying to test which outgoing ports are allowed through a firewall. At the moment I can do this for TCP by port scanning `portquiz.net` (which is a server with all TCP ports open) from inside however this won’t work for UDP.

My setup is as follows:
`Me (my device on local network) <-> NAT/Firewall <-> IPv4 Internet`

So my question is, how can I test a firewall between me and the Internet to see which outgoing UDP ports I am able to connect to and use successfully?

For clarification I'm wanting to test every port (not any particular port) and returning a list of the ports that can successfully get through.

Comment: Hi CallumA.  This is asking for a service recommendation and so is off-topic.  Consider rewording the question.

Comment: Do you have access to your own device externally?

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure what you mean, the firewall (and NAT) means incoming connections are not allowed at all if that's it.

Comment: You are testing outgoing connections, do you have something external you could target?  This would be straightforward if you have your own machine on the internet you could use to listen for connections.

Comment: @Paul Ahh, I see. Yes, I do have a server that could be used for this.

Comment: a server on the internet might require port forwarding. you could test on a server on your LAN. so installing cygwin and using the nc command something like `nc -ul 1234`  and then on the computer whose outgoing firewall rule you are testing, do `nc -u 192.168.1.7 1234`

Answer (score 5):

This tool will do it.  You can enter the entire 1-65,535 UDP port range.

http://demo1.speedsight.com/applet.html

Comment: This test uses java applet. Latest chrome versions block java. use firefox.

Comment: Does this utility exist in an offline form that could be used to scan ports on networks that use paywalls or something of that nature.

Comment: There does not seem to be a web server on the address any more: `ncat -vv demo1.speedsight.com 80` --- `TCP connection requested to 34.195.111.169:80 (IOD #1) EID 8` --- `CONNECT TIMEOUT for EID 8 [34.195.111.169:80]`.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a server available that you can target the scan against, you can use tcpdump or similar.  This works by having a machine inside the firewall try and send a udp packet to a server outside the firewall on every port.  The receiving server then records the packets it sees.

First make sure that all incoming UDP ports are forwarded to the server on the router (if it is not directly on the internet).

Then run tcpdump

```
  tcpdump -i eth0 host <ip address of remote server> proto udp
```

The ip address of the remote server is whatever your IP appears to be after NAT through the firewall. There are services online to work out your public IP address.

Then from a device inside the firewall, use nmap:

```
  nmap -sU <your server IP> -p 1-65536
```

The `nmap` will tell you nothing, but the `tcpdump` at the remote site will record every udp packet that came through the firewall.